# JNLP files won't launch from IE11 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, jnlp

Since May 9, after a windows 10 update, on IE11 11.0.40, JNLP files wont launch from IE, but in a computer with IE version 11.0.34 it work perfectly.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked that the .jnlp file association is present/correct? 
i.e. in Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Default Programs > Set Associations  verify that there is a line with Name=.jnlp, Description=JNLP File and Current Default=Java(TM) Web Start Launcher

Comment: Are there maybe any other solutions than de-installing the 64 bit version of java?

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem opening a jnlp file, no matter what, trying to associate it with the Java Web Service exe javaws.exe, but it just would not associate and would not be run. I read throughout forums and all, and in the end from old DOS.exe files that I have used, somehow I did that and a miracle, it worked, I simply dragged the saved jnlp file and dropped it onto the javaws.exe, and it was executed. wanted to share this...

Answer (score 1):

Alex, it appears our friends at Oracle heard you loud and clear.  According to the JDK Bug System, this issue is being tracked under defect [JDK-8185661](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8185661).   The fix appears to be in the pipeline for inclusion in an upcoming Critical Patch Update (CPU).

In the meantime, it is possible to test the fix on a development system using an early access build downloaded via Oracle's [Java Early Access Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html) page.   After reproducing the issue with JRE 8u151 (1.8.0_151-b12) on a Windows 10 version 1703 system, using IE 11.0.44, I verified the issue as fixed after updating to early-access JRE 8u162 (1.8.0_162-ea-b01).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved in Java 8 u162. Now you can have Java RE x86 and x64 installed and jnlp will open as it should in Internet Explorer. We are using sitelist / Enterprise Mode to redirect jnlp urls from Edge to Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing Windows 10 creators update.

Reason/Solution: I had both the 32-bit and the 64-bit JRE installed on my computer (Java 8 Update 131). This was not a problem before the creators update. Java applets and Java webstart applications have worked fine in Internet Explorer 11. However, Internet Explorer 11 (11.332.15063.0) seems to have problems with the 64-bit JRE. Java Webstart applications can only started if only a 32-bit JRE is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I uninstalled Java x64 and it solved my problem with jnlp-file that didn't start.