# Looking for actual fix for running JNLP with 64 bit Java launched from IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, java-8, ldap, x86-64

I was not able to make a comment on the question  [JNLP files won't launch from IE11 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058428/jnlp-files-wont-launch-from-ie11-on-windows-10) because I am relatively new to StackOverflow.

I wanted to know if anyone had a better solution than uninstalling the 64 bit JRE or if they know that Oracle or Microsoft knows the issue?

I have latest Java 8 x64 (1.8.0_144) JDK which installs the accompanying JRE.

When I connect to my server to get and deploy my webstart application in Internet Explorer 11, I see a flash of the browsers Download popup that says that 8.8KB of webstart.jnlp was downloaded and it has buttons to Cancel or Show Downloads. (It took many tries to catch the text since it disappears quickly.)  The application never loads and the jnlp file does not show up in the View Downloads of IE.
Also it never gets to the point of launching Jave as I have the console showing with all of the Debugging options on. So it appears it is in the Java x64 Java plugin for IE.

The above question had a workaround to use the 32 bit version of the JRE and I tested that (after uninstalling several other 64 bit JREs) and things do work. The problem is I need the 64 bit version to operate properly. Also our software is deployed at various sites and to have them remove their Java 8 x64 JREs will be a problem.

Is there anything else I can check or to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the `<j2se version="1.7+" sun.arch.data.model="64" >`
does what it promises..
[(Oracle FAQ)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_detection)

I Use SystExternals Process Explorer to catch information of processes which start and are gone again, since PE keeps them in the table a bit longer for user convenience. It marks new processes green and terminated processes red for a few seconds.

Also, you could [enable Deployment tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48783499/147673)