# JNLP file doesn't work on windows 10 x64

Tags: java, windows-10, java-web-start, jnlp

I have Windows 10 pro. x64. I have jnlp file, that works on many different laptops, but not mine. So usually jnlp file opens a window with application. Not on mine machine. When i double click on jnlp or run it using `jawaws file.jnlp` what happens is Java(TM) web launcher and Java (TM ) Web Start Launcher is active in processes in task manager..

So, each time i run jnlp program, it runs web launcher and web start launcher but doesn't run program.

What is curious, sometimes but seldomly, it opens java window and generate error message then, during jawaws run.

What i tried is to reinstall jre. I was using x86 and x64 versions. 1.8.161

I tried editing jnlp file according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912676/i-am-not-able-launch-jnlp-applications-using-java-web-start) solution. I changed max heap size to 780 mb, initial heap from 256 to 512 and 1024 and max heap to 1024. It can't help.

I deleted cache of java applications, still not helped. 
I changed JAVA_HOME to my 32 bits jre ( before it was pointing to j2se sdk ). 
Still without proper solution.

I also deleted temporary internet files for all options.

Other jnlp run properly. In jnlp file there is sdk 1.7+ defined.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the webstart trace file for a clue of what's wrong?

From the Java Control Panel 'advanced' tab, select `Debugging->"Enable tracing"`

And set the trace level to 'all':

[image]

Trace files are written here:

```
c:\Users\<user>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\log\ *.trace
```

Comment: i forgot to mention to edit the deployment.properties file. Hence the edit of the answer.

Comment: I enabled logging, tracing and applet lifecycle. I added two lines to deployment.properties in folder below. I can't see any files except jcp.trace. But in jcp.trace nothing appears during running jnlp program.

Comment: you said "Other jnlp run properly". Does it generate a trace file then?

Comment: Yes. After succesfully run this app it started to generate trace files.  it seems that jawaws didn't work properly with new java update.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by downgrading java update to older updates.